# SQLite. Can't add more than 1000 rows

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite, fmdb

I'm trying to add to my SQLite database (with fmdb) 10k rows but writing is stopped on 1000 row. And I have no any errors or warnings. My code:

```
NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into histories (storyid, text, date, storyurl) values (%li, ?, ?, ?)",history.storyIndex];
if ([self.db open]) {
    if([self.db executeUpdate:queryString, history.storyText, history.storyDate, history.storyUrl]) {
        NSLog(@"history added");
    } 
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: ... with a mixture of printf-formatting and bind variables?!?

Comment: @H2CO3 there are many examples with lowercase SQL query. Has it bad effect for performance?

Comment: @RomanHouse don't worry, it's fine. You just don't have enough experience with stuff yet to understand the punchline :)

Comment: @H2CO3 lets dont delay this :) I will be glad if you give me some reason to use uppercase queries :)

Comment: @RomanHouse It's just idiomatic. Lowercase is also fine, and there's no difference, but people tend to use SQL queries in all-caps. (Yeah, this pretty much indicates that database engineers are noobs. :P)

Comment: @H2CO3 ok, I will be use uppercase queries and become professional at once :D

Comment: What error does sqlite produce?

Comment: @trojanfoe there are no any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following code and see if there is any change:

```
NSString *queryString = @"INSERT INTO histories (storyid, text, date, storyurl) 
VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?)";

BOOL executeUpdateStatus = NO;

if ([self.db open]) 
{
    executeUpdateStatus = [self.db executeUpdate:queryString, 
    [NSNumber numberWithLong:history.storyIndex], history.storyText,
    history.storyDate, history.storyUrl];


        if(executeUpdateStatus == YES)   
            NSLog(@"history added");
        else
            NSLog(@"history NOT added");
}
```

Comment: You should only open your database only once, and don't forget to use `[self.db commit];`

Answer (score 5):

For anyone with the same problem... make sure your sqlite viewer is not limiting the output of your query to 1000 results.

Just lost a few minutes with the same problem and the answer was that simple!

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you. SQLite studio was in fact showing only 1000 records. Confirmed it with a query and then removed the limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Put the *database open* outside of the loop, so that it is called just the once. Calling it repeatedly inside the loop of 10,000 rows might be causing memory problems.

Check for lastErrorCode on the db object after each executeUpdate and NSLog the lastErrorMessage if it is non zero.

Commit at intervals by incrementing a counter and using modulus arithmetic, e.g.

```
counter++;
if (mod(counter,500) ){
    [self.db commit];
}
```

Consider using python to bulk load the database outside of the iOS project.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to commit your transactions. It appears that you have reached some limit on the amount of rows in a single transaction.

Comment: I already trying to commit each of transactions but it isn't help