# change the default setting for the SQLite query record output limit in SQLite studio 3.0.7

Tags: sqlitestudio

How to change the default setting for the SQLite query record output limit in SQLite studio 3.0.7 ?

it is alway 1000 records even though i used :

```
 select * from mytable limit 2000;
```

It was mentioned in

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118610/sqlite-cant-add-more-than-1000-rows
```

But, do not show how.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Configuration` dialog, then to `Data browsing` and adjust `Number of data rows per page`.